# how to call submit function manually - jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I have a form using jquery validation plugin. My submit button has an ajax handler, via which i want to call a binding method , when the button is clicked. I added some javascript to be run, before the ajax method is called. I want to call some method in the jquery validation plugin, which will return true or false, which will tell me if the form is valid or not, then i can continue my ajax call .

```
<h:commandButton id="altButton" tabindex="26" onclick="return processSubmit();"     styleClass="input" value="I'm ready!">
  <f:ajax> execute="@form" event="click" render="" listener="#{signup$MASSignupHandler.submitApplication}"/>
</h:commandButton>

function processSubmit(){
   var temp = jQuery('#mainForm').submit();
   alert ("done validation")
   return true
}
```

the above method does do the validation, but this method still returns true and my ajax method gets called no matter if there's a validation error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mainForm").submit() {
     //check if validations are fine
     if(validatedFine) {  /your condition that checks if validation went fine
        return true;
     }
     else {
        return false;
     }
  });
});
```

Hope it helps